# Chart.js Line Graph: Start a line in the middle of a graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a graph with multiple lines, but I want one of the lines to start from the middle of the graph, while the rest of the lines still start from all the way at the left. Is this possible? It'd look like this:
[image: The green line is what I want to do]

The green line is what I am talking about, whether it would be possible for a dataset to start from not all the way at the left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can achieve this in 2 ways:

1. specify each datapoint using its x and y coordinate
2. place some `null` values in the start of your data array:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: 3,
          y: 6
        }, {
          x: 4,
          y: 8
        }, {
          x: 5,
          y: 2
        }, {
          x: 6,
          y: 12
        }],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points2',
        data: [null, null, null, 9, 13, 15],
        borderColor: 'lightblue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly do this with `offset` option.

**Example:**

```
 const options = {
   ...otherChartOptions,
   
   scales: {
     x: {
       offset: true
     },
     y: {
       offset: true
     }
   }
 };
```

Reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html